# send dynamic email in Laravel with SwiftMailer

Tags: php, laravel

i want send dynamic email after registration form in laravel.
my codes are:

```
$gift = new Gift();
        $gift->user_id = Auth::id();
        $gift->register_user = $request->input('email');
        $gift->status = 0;
        $gift->amount = 10;
        $gift->code = uniqid('coinex-');
        if ($gift->save()) {
            $data = array('code'=>$gift->code,'friend'=>Auth::user()->name,'email'=> $gift->register_user);
            $email =  $gift->register_user;
            Mail::send('invite', $data, function($message) {
                $message->to("Receiver_Email_address", Auth::user()->name.' Invited you to Join site')->subject
                (Auth::user()->name.' Invited you to Join Coinex Plus');
                $message->from('info@site.com','site');
            });
            toast('Thank you for your cooperation !', 'success');
            return redirect()->back();
        } else {
            toast('something wrong please try again !', 'danger');
            return redirect()->back();
        }
```

how can i replace **Receiver_Email_address** with **$email** ?

Comment: in receiver email address, use email that you get in registration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the variable to a closure using `use` keyword.

Below is the sample code to do that:

```
Mail::send($invite, $data, function ($message) use ($email) {
     $message->to($email, Auth::user()->name.' Invited you to Join site')->subject
            (Auth::user()->name.' Invited you to Join Coinex Plus');
            $message->from('info@site.com','site');
}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Best.

Comment: Please accept it as the answer so that the question will be closed. @Amirali

Answer (score 2):

You can also pass multiple variables by passing them like: `use($variable1, $variable2)`

Try this:

```
Mail::send('invite', $data, function($message) use ($email){
 $message->to($email, Auth::user()->name.' Invited you to Join site')->subject
 (Auth::user()->name.' Invited you to Join Coinex Plus');
 $message->from('info@site.com','site');
});
```